# SAP Table Connector cannot find FM in SAP ECC 6

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, sap-dotnet-connector

Our version of SAP (ECC6 EHP 0) does not have the FM ZRFC_READ_TABLE2. We created a copy and called it ZFM_INTERNAL_ZRFC_READ_TABLE2; however, when trying to use it from ADF with the SAP connector (version 3.0.23 64bit) we get an error.

Type: SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcInvalidParameterException

Message: Element QUERY_TABLE of container metadata XXXXX/ZFM_INTERNAL_ZRFC_READ_TABLE2 unknown.

I posted this question in the GitHub feedback page ([link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/62650#issue-701809327)) and was told this is a better forum to answer this type of questions.

The FM has the QUERY_TABLE parameter and it has been tested to be working (using Python scripts).
Screenshots of the configuration and tests performed.

[FM Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1zTm.png)

[Test Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91KGL.png)

[Test Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yewbT.png)

Any ideas where the problem could be?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As discussed in [Microsoft Q&A Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/96758/data-factory-sap-table-connector-cannot-find-fm-in.html) the above issue can be resolved if we are specifying function module alone without the function group.

Answer (score 0):

Under Attribute tab, make sure you select "Remote-Enabled Module".
[image]

Comment: As @Carlos said (in the answer below) the "remote-enabled module" option is already selected. 
Any other ideas?

Comment: In this case, the next possible cause is insufficient authorization of the SAP user you use. Please check if there is SU53 security error message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; howerver, we are using the same user from Python scripts and they run correctly, which would indicate the security is set properly, right?
Anything else you think we can look at?

Comment: I'll volunteer 30 minutes to help you on this (there is no catch. it's just a way to add tiny value to the community). Contact me at chunhui at aecorsoft dot com. We can find a time during the day time of pacific time zone.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. We worked with Microsoft on this and have found a workaround. Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/96758/data-factory-sap-table-connector-cannot-find-fm-in.html) if you are interested. 
Closing the question.

Comment: I see. So the root cause was the masked prefix which was actually not an SAP name space but your function group name. If this (incorrect) style was also used in pyrfc, then there should have been failure as well.